# LINUX- Checking the internal CPU, RAM usage of JVM's

Tags: linux, jvm

So I am trying to check the internal CPU and RAM usage from JVM's.

The set up is that we have a single server which hosts 39 JVM's each running its own service and has it's own unique CPU & RAM allocation. So for example it could be set up like the following:

```
      CPU(Cores)   RAM(MB)
JVM1      2          300
JVM2      1          50
JVM3      5          1024
```

These are fictional as I don't have the actual values to hand.

I know the PID's for each of the JVM's but I am wondering how would I see the CPU and RAM usage of each JVM on it's own dissregarding the Host systems usage. Also is it possible to pass multiple `PID`'s into a `jstat -gc` as I will be looking to script this?.

I know that if I use:

```
ps -p <PID> -o %CPU %RAM
```

That will give me the CPU and RAM of that process on the host machine.

Any Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: [`/proc/pid/stat`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) and `/proc/pid/status` might help.

Comment: @apangin This is a interesting read and I didn't know some of it but I am not seeing any figures that match what I am seeing in our application.

Comment: If you have 39 JVM's of service you must have a big team. If you have less developers than JVM I would consider reducing the number.  I would use top to see much RAM or CPU each process is using.

Comment: you might want to read up on the various [CLI monitoring tools](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/). `jps` for example makes it easy to find running JVMs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around for a while I came up with the following script which pulls the memory usage and total memory in use to 2DP:

## Script

```
#!/bin/sh

service=$(mktemp)
jstatop=$(mktemp)
ServiceStatsPre=$(mktemp)
datet=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
hourt=$(date +%H)

ps -ef | grep  java | grep Service | awk '{key=substr($9,31,match($9,"@")-31); serv[key]++}END{for(name in serv){if($9 ~ /Service/){print name}}}'>$service

printf "%-8sService\t\t\t\t%7s   PID\t%7s  Used\t%7s  Total\n" > $ServiceStatsPre

filename=$service
while read -r line; do
if [ ! -z $line ]; then
pid=$(ps -ef | grep  java | grep Service |awk -v svc="$line" '{if (match($9,svc)){print $2}}')
rncnt=0
rnag=1
        while [ $rnag -eq 1 ]; do
                jstat -gc $pid > $jstatop
                if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
                        sleep 5;
                        rncnt++;
                else
                rnag=0
                fi
                if [ $rncnt -eq 5 ]; then
                        rnag=0
                fi
        done
cat $jstatop | awk '{if (NR !=1) print}'|awk -v pid="$pid" -v svc="$line" -v d="$datet" -v h="$hourt" '{printf("%-40s %7d %6.2fMB %6.2fMB %11s %3s\n",svc,pid,($1+$5+$7)/1024,($3+$4+$6+$8)/1024,d,h)}' >> $ServiceStatsPre
fi
done < $filename
#printf "Date,Hour,Service,Used,Total\n" > Service_Stats.csv  #Uncomment this line on initial Run to create file with headders
cat $ServiceStatsPre | awk '{if (NR !=1) print}' |
awk '{
printf("%-1s,%1s,%1s,%4.2f,%4.2f\n",$5,$6,$1,$3,$4);
}' >> Service_Stats.csv

rm $service;
rm $jstatop;
rm $ServiceStatsPre;
```

## Breakdown

```
ps -ef | grep  java | grep Service | awk '{key=substr($9,31,match($9,"@")-31); serv[key]++}END{for(name in serv){if($9 ~ /Service/){print name}}}'>$service
```

This is returning the name of the Service and putting it to a tempary file `$service`

```
printf "%-8sService\t\t\t\t%7s   PID\t%7s  Used\t%7s  Total\n" > $ServiceStatsPre
```

This is just creating Headings in a Temp file `$ServiceStatsPre` (I know this isn't needed but I was originally using it to debug to a file not a temp file)

### Outer While loop

```
filename=$service
if [ ! -z $line ]; then
while read -r line; do
pid=$(ps -ef | grep  java | grep Service |awk -v svc="$line" '{if (match($9,svc)){print $2}}')
rncnt=0
rnag=1
...
cat $jstatop | awk '{if (NR !=1) print}'|awk -v pid="$pid" -v svc="$line" -v d="$datet" -v h="$hourt" '{printf("%-40s %7d %6.2fMB %6.2fMB %11s %3s\n",svc,pid,($1+$5+$7)/1024,($3+$4+$6+$8)/1024,d,h)}' >> $ServiceStatsPre
fi
done < $filename
```

This is first checking to see if the line that it is passing in is not empty (`if [ ! -z $line ]; then`) then it is extracting the `PID` for each of the services in the temp file `$service` and is setting a check (`rnag`) + retry counter (`rncnt`). The final part of this outer while loop is calculating the stats, memory usage in `MB` (`($1+$5+$7)/1024`), Total Memory used (`($3+$4+$6+$8)/1024`) as well as retuning the `PID`,Service Name,Date and Hour.

### Inner While Loop

```
...
while [ $rnag -eq 1 ]; do
                jstat -gc $pid > $jstatop
                if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
                        sleep 5;
                        rncnt++;
                else
                rnag=0
                fi
                if [ $rncnt -eq 5 ]; then
                        rnag=0
                fi
        done
...
```

This is to basically ensure that the `jstat` is running correctly and isn't returning an error.

The final part of this script:

```
#printf "Date,Hour,Service,Used,Total\n" > Service_Stats.csv  #Uncomment this line on initial Run to create file with headders
cat $ServiceStatsPre | awk '{if (NR !=1) print}' |
awk '{
printf("%-1s,%1s,%1s,%4.2f,%4.2f\n",$5,$6,$1,$3,$4);
}' >> Service_Stats.csv
```

is just to resolve the formatting and put it into a format so that it can be used in a `CSV`.

### Output

This script out puts like the following:

```
Date,Hour,Service,Used,Total
2016-07-03,07,undMFSAdapterServiceVM,331.00,188.87
2016-07-03,07,entSCSServiceVM,332.50,278.19
2016-07-03,07,kServiceVM,457.50,132.91
2016-07-03,07,ServiceTuTrackVm,432.00,282.66
2016-07-03,07,ter1WMSAdapterServiceVm,233.00,77.02
2016-07-03,07,kingMFSAdapterServiceVM,451.50,126.69
2016-07-03,07,erBuilderServiceVM,261.50,211.27
2016-07-03,07,ter3MFSAdapterServiceVM,449.50,210.23
2016-07-03,07,rServiceVM1,1187.00,529.26
2016-07-03,07,rServiceVM2,597.50,398.43
2016-07-03,07,rServiceVM3,2786.00,819.30
2016-07-03,07,rServiceVM4,451.50,163.13
2016-07-03,07,MessagingServiceVm,457.50,357.11
2016-07-03,07,viceVM,444.50,263.59
2016-07-03,07,ServiceVM,1910.50,909.19
2016-07-03,07,undPackingMFSAdapterServiceVM,208.00,113.51
2016-07-03,07,gisticLockServiceVM,245.00,173.05
2016-07-03,07,kingMFSAdapterServiceVM,781.50,327.13
2016-07-03,07,ferWMSAdapterServiceVm,196.00,84.02
2016-07-03,07,geMFSAdapterServiceVM,499.50,256.91
2016-07-03,07,ferMFSAdapterServiceVM,456.50,246.89
2016-07-03,07,kingWMSAdapterServiceVm,195.00,73.70
2016-07-03,07,AdapterServiceVm,149.50,72.62
2016-07-03,07,ter2MFSAdapterServiceVM,455.00,136.02
2016-07-03,07,ionServiceVM,484.00,240.46
2016-07-03,07,ter3WMSAdapterServiceVm,266.00,138.70
2016-07-03,07,iceVm,135.50,106.07
2016-07-03,07,viceVm,3317.00,1882.15
2016-07-03,07,entBCSServiceVM,356.50,143.93
2016-07-03,07,ServiceVm,951.00,227.12
2016-07-03,07,lingServiceVM,145.50,76.61
2016-07-03,07,entDBHServiceVM,182.50,4.63
2016-07-03,07,kingWMSAdapterServiceVm,208.00,103.13
2016-07-03,07,gingServiceVM,1529.50,235.84
2016-07-03,07,ServiceVM,249.50,131.78
2016-07-03,07,ter1MFSAdapterServiceVM,453.00,394.11
2016-07-03,07,AdapterServiceVM,461.00,208.41
2016-07-03,07,ter2WMSAdapterServiceVm,178.50,79.93
2016-07-03,07,AdapterServiceVm,395.00,131.08
2016-07-03,07,ingServiceVM,184.50,126.28
```

The `$3` has been trimmed just to hide service names etc..

### Helpful Links

[A nice explanation of jstat -gc output](http://www.cubrid.org/blog/dev-platform/how-to-monitor-java-garbage-collection/)